# Do we have $P(Y_n\ge \Phi^{-1}(1-\alpha)) \le \alpha？$

Tags: probability, statistics

If for a sequence of random variables $X_n\sim ^{iid} N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ we have
$$
Y_n:=\sqrt{n}(X_n-E[X])/\sigma \sim N(0,1)
$$ I want to bound $$P(Y_n\ge \Phi^{-1}(1-\alpha))$$

Do we have
$$P(Y_n\ge \Phi^{-1}(1-\alpha)) \le \alpha？$$

Comment: What is $X_n$? The mean of some iid observations with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, normally distributed or not?

Comment: @Henry Yes, that is fine.

Comment: I think you are taking the mean so $Y_n:=\sqrt{n}(\bar X_n-E[X])/\sigma \sim N(0,1)$.  But anyway, if $Y_n\sim N(0,1)$ then  $P(Y_n\ge \Phi^{-1}(1-\alpha))=P(Y_n\gt \Phi^{-1}(1-\alpha)) $ $= 1- P(Y_n\le \Phi^{-1}(1-\alpha)) $ $= 1- \Phi( \Phi^{-1}(1-\alpha)) $ $= 1-(1-\alpha) $ $= \alpha$